# Optional like initialization of custom type

Tags: swift

I wonder if there is a way to implement custom type initialization with another type like it is in Optionals:

`var optional: Optional<Type> = Type()`

Here’s I want to achieve:

`var custom: CustomType<AnotherType> = AnotherType()`

I know there are ExpressibleBy protocols that allow you to initialize type with literal, but not with type.
It works as you can initialize variable like this:

`var num: CustomType = 5`

But not like this:

`var num: CustomType = Int(5)`

And only with such literal ExpressibleBy provides, but my goal is to do it with every type.

So is there a way to do what I want and how?

Comment: The code of `Optional` is [open source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift).

Comment: That's not possible. `Optional` works like this by compiler magic. What does `CustomType` do? Perhaps it can be a property wrapper instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit casts (like C#'s [user-defined implicit conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) and C++'s [user-defined conversion functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)) aren't supported in Swift, and intentionally so.

Swift's design *heavily* optimizes for clarity at the call-site (e.g. with heavy use of argument labels), and such implicit conversions introduce the ability for arbitrary magic to happen, with no hint of its existence from the call site.

Some exceptions are made for particularly common and harmless cases:

1. Optionals have special treatment from the compiler, allowing non-optional values to be implicitly promoted to optionals when needed. This is a pretty straight-forward readability win, and doesn't introduce any risk of confusion. As a point of comparison, Rust doesn't do this, so you see `.ok()` a lot.
2. `ExpressibleByXLiteral` protocols implement something similar. They only apply to literals though, so in some sense, when you have an object that's initialized with an integer literal, *there was never an `Int` to begin with*. It's more of a hook into the language syntax, than an implicit conversion operator (hence why it only applies to literals and not arbitrary expressions)

Comment: Thanks, I had already understand that it’s impossible.

Comment: I mean, that’s pretty much the answer to the question, as stated. ‍♂️